# UISnapBehaviour in x-axis only

Tags: ios, uikit-dynamics, uisnapbehavior

Is there anyway to get UISnapBevahiour to only work along a linear x-axis?

I want the exact behaviour of a UISnapBehaviour but don't want it to 'shake' into position on both x & y axis, just the x axis.

This is for a UIView inside my contentView of a table cell.

> ```
> // UIKitDynamics
> self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self];
> CGPoint centerPoint = self.contentView.center;
> self.snapBehaviour = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.frontView snapToPoint:centerPoint];
> [self.snapBehaviour setDamping:1.0f];
> [self.animator addBehavior:self.snapBehaviour];
> UIDynamicItemBehavior *itemBehaviour = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.frontView]];
> itemBehaviour.elasticity = 0.0f;
> itemBehaviour.allowsRotation = NO;
> [self.animator addBehavior:itemBehaviour];
> ```

Comment: Hmmm interesting, I was going to suggest adding another dynamic item behaviour and setting rotation to NO but I see you've already done that. I used that approach to make it work in the y axis. I went this route but ended up simplifying by using a UIView animation call with spring damping which did exactly what I needed without having to dip into UIKit Dynamics (as fun as that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the code I used to do a similar thing, as I mentioned in my comment it used UIView animation that leverage UIKit Dynamics underneath as opposed to using them directly...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
      initialSpringVelocity:0.3
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                   [toView setFrame:_modalFrame];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   [self.context completeTransition:YES];
                 }];
```

This presents modal view which springs up and oscillates a bit on presentation.

Comment: Yes my old implementation uses animations.

Comment: The answer by @Cocoadelica is the correct one. I tried using UIKit Dynamics however it was impossible to lock a UISnapBehaviour to the x axis.

Answer (score 5):

From [UIDynamicBehavior documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicBehavior_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDynamicBehavior/action) of it's `action` block:

> `@property(nonatomic, copy) void (^action)(void)`
>
> The dynamic animator calls the action block on every animation step.

So when creating your behaviour, do something like this:

```
UIView *view = ...
UIAttachmentBehavior *attachment = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:view attachedToAnchor:point];
    
CGFloat xCoordinate = view.frame.origin.x;
attachment.action = ^{
   if (view.frame.origin.x != xCoordinate) {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = xCoordinate;
        view.frame = frame;
    }
};

[self.dynamicAnimator addBehavior:attachment];
```

In my example I use a UIAttachmentBehavior but this method will also work for any other subclass of UIDynamicBehavior, in your case a UISnapBehavior.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Does this work when there are multiple active behaviors though?